# How do I test an OpenCV SVM?

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

I have used the OpenCV SVM from this example http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html.

Now I need to test the accuracy of this SVM for my predicted values.This is the part of my code for predicting the accuracy of the SVM.

```
void svm(cv::Mat& trainingDataMat, cv::Mat& labelsMat, cv::Mat& Testdata) {
int t=0;
int f=0;
int Acc;
 CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);
CvSVM SVM;
SVM.train(trainingDataMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);
cv::Mat predicted(1,1, CV_32F);

for(int i = 0; i < Testdata.rows; i++) {
    cv::Mat sample = Testdata.row(i);
    predicted.at<float>(i,0)= SVM.predict(sample);
    float p = predicted.at<float>(i,0);

    if (p > 0.0) || p<0.0) {
        t++;
    }
    else {
        f++;
    }

    Acc=(t*1.0)/(t+f);
    }
  cout << "Accuracy_{SVM} = " <<Acc << endl;
   }
```

I am trying to test a single test data at a time and find out whether each column in a row belongs to the positive or negative side of a trained classifier and its accuracy of prediction.

The problem I am facing with this code is that the percentage of prediction is always shown as 100.

I find this a little odd and would like someone to help me in this matter?

Comment: You need to show us your best effort to date

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem lies in the detection of "true" and "false", in fact your code should not even compile (1 opening bracet and 2 closing ones)

```
if (p > 0.0) || p<0.0) {
        t++;
    }
    else {
        f++;
    }
```

you are giving your model a "point" iff `p!=0.0`, so you aleays get a 100%. You should compare the prediction of your SVM with the **true** value of this point. And if they are the same -- increase the `t` counter, and increase `f` otherwise.